# CROSS JOIN of list of dates and another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query for getting data from a certain table by date range and grouping by week. My CROSS JOIN intends to fill in a default value for each week where there are no results for the date range.

I can then execute this query.

```
    SELECT 
        SUM(invoice.amount) AS "invoice.amount", 
        CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(invoice.updated_at, '%b %d'), ' - ', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(invoice.updated_at, INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%b %d')) AS "invoice.updated_at"
    FROM invoice
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT selected_date 
        FROM (
            SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date 
            FROM
                (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
                (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
                (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
                (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
        ) v
        WHERE selected_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31'
        GROUP BY selected_date, YEAR(selected_date), WEEK(selected_date)
    ) calendar
    WHERE invoice.updated_at >= '2018-01-01' 
        AND invoice.updated_at <= '2018-01-31'
        AND invoice.status = "PAID"
    GROUP BY calendar.selected_date, invoice.id, invoice.amount, YEAR(invoice.updated_at), WEEK(invoice.updated_at)
```

Assume I have these records in the database:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id |   amount   |   status   | updated_at | 
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |    1000    |    PAID    | 2018-01-01 |
|  2 |    2000    |    PAID    | 2018-01-01 |
|  3 |    100     |    PAID    | 2018-01-07 |
|  4 |    50      |    PAID    | 2018-01-11 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

I expect to see these results, one record for every week of January:

```
+--------+-------------------+
| amount |     updated_at    | 
+--------+-------------------+
|  3100  |  Jan 1  - Jan 7   |
|  50    |  Jan 8  - Jan 15  |
|  0     |  Jan 16 - Jan 22  |
|  0     |  Jan 23 - Jan 30  |
|  0     |  Jan 31 - Jan 31  |
+--------+-------------------+
```

However, I get like 50 of these random duplicated results, the least of which contains the joined filler weeks since there are no 0 amounts:

```
+--------+----------------+
| amount |   updated_at   | 
+--------+----------------+
|  1000  | Jan 1 - Jan 7  |
|  2000  | Jan 1 - Jan 7  |
|  100   | Jan 1 - Jan 7  |
|  50    | Jan 8 - Jan 15 |
|  1000  | Jan 1 - Jan 7  |
|  1000  | Jan 1 - Jan 7  |
|  2000  | Jan 1 - Jan 7  |
|  2000  | Jan 1 - Jan 7  |
|  100   | Jan 1 - Jan 7  |
|  50    | Jan 8 - Jan 15 |
|  100   | Jan 1 - Jan 7  |
|  50    | Jan 8 - Jan 15 |
|  ...   | ...            |
|  ...   | ...            |
|  ...   | ...            |
+--------+----------------+
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

> GROUP BY calendar.selected_date, invoice.id, invoice.amount,

You have too many columns specified in the group by, particularly `invoice.amount`

Instead, try with:

```
GROUP BY
    CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(invoice.updated_at, '%b %d'), ' - ', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(invoice.updated_at, INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%b %d'))
```

---

I cannot be sure, but I think your date range needs adjustment as well, the following will guarantee you get everything for January 2018:

```
WHERE invoice.updated_at >= '2018-01-01' 
    AND invoice.updated_at < '2018-02-01'
```